# How to trigger nightly Jenkins pipeline job using a GitHub repository

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a GitHub repository which contains a `Jenkinsfile` (with job configuration steps). I want to trigger a Jenkins simple `Pipeline` (not multibranch) job every night to build a jar from this repo and deploy to Nexus.

The pipeline definition options says read `Pipeline script from SCM` but then I don't see any option to point to specific SCM i.e. GitHub in my case. I can write the pipeline script in the Job but that is not what I want.

How can I achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a build trigger for Build periodically to the jenkins job.
This will build it on a schedule for you.

You will need to install the [Git Client Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin)

Then you will get the following option:
[image: option for pipeline git]

Under it you will be able to put the location of the git repo and the  credentials.

Comment: My main problem is how the job will know where the repository is. As I mentioned the SCM option is not present